# En python pandas ¿Cómo resolver el error cannot reindex from a duplicate axis?

Tags: python, pandas

En una tabla de nómina quiero cálcular el valor de la prima dominical considerando si el trabajador laboró el dia domingo y en base a su salario.

la prima dominical es igual a Salario base diario * .25 (siempre y cúando el trabajador haya laborado el domingo).

para calcular la prima dominical utilizo la siguiente instrucción

```
grupo_p1.loc[grupo_p1["DOMINGO TRABAJADO"]=="SI",
              "PRIM DOM"]=107*.257
```

donde 107 es el salario base diario. Este cálculo se hace sin problema, sin embargo, si yo quiero tomar el dato del salario de una columna de la misma tabla

```
grupo_p1['SALARIO']
```

la misma instrucción la escribo de esta manera

```
grupo_p1.loc[grupo_p1["DOMINGO TRABAJADO"]=="SI",
              "PRIM DOM"]=grupo_p1['SALARIO']*.25
```

pero Jupyter notebook me arroja el siguiente error

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

¿cómo tengo que escribir esta instrucción para que no se genere el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la asignación:

```
grupo_p1.loc[grupo_p1["DOMINGO TRABAJADO"]=="SI",
              "PRIM DOM"]=grupo_p1['SALARIO']*.25
```

el lado izquierdo no tiene el mismo número de filas que el lado derecho, pues el lado izquierdo es resultado de un filtrado que se habrá quedado sólo con algunas filas, mientras que el derecho es la columna completa.

Prueba así:

```
seleccion = grupo_p1["DOMINGO TRABAJADO"]=="SI"
grupo_p1.loc[seleccion,"PRIM DOM"] = grupo_p1.loc[seleccion, 'SALARIO']*.25
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, si funcionó. En tu opinión ¡que es más eficiente? utilizar la sintaxis como la propones o hacer reset_index al dataframe. En ambos casos aparentemente tengo el mismo resultado.

Comment: Supongo que si los índices están correctos, el intento de asignar una columna derecha a una selección menor se traducirá en que pandas asignará sólo a los elementos cuyo índice aparezca en ambos lados. Al final tendrá que ir comparando índices, lo cual vendrá a ser equivalente a ir comparando qué elementos de `seleccion` son true para seleccionar sólo esos. No sabría decir a priori qué es más eficiente, habría que medirlo.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que leí en otros posts, el error se debe a que los índices están duplicados, lo que hice fue utilizar reset_index( )

```
grupo_p1.reset_index(drop=False, inplace = True)
```

Después de esto, ya obtuve el resultado deseado.